# InvalidCastException on UltraWebGrid Infragistics asp.net

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I am getting an

```
 InvalidCastException was unhandled by user: 
   Conversion from String "ORDERDATE" to type "Integer" is not valid.
```

The error hits when it gets to the lines with `band.SortedColumns`. 
Any idea why i get this error?

I have the same code for `infragistics UltraWinGrid` `vb.net` and I don't get that error.

```
        UltraWebGrid1.DataSource = Nothing
        myDataName = Generic.getPrevOrder(dt, username)
        UltraWebGrid1.DataSource = dt

        Dim band As Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.UltraGridBand = UltraWebGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0)
        UltraWebGrid1.DisplayLayout.ViewType = Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.ViewType.OutlookGroupBy

        band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("ORDERDATE"), True)
        band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("ORDERID"), False)
```

Comment: I managed to fix my problem by changing the band.Columns("ORDERDATE") to band.Columns.IndexOf("ORDERDATE")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be nothing, but out of curiosity, what happens if you swap these around:

```
band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("ORDERDATE"), True)
band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("ORDERID"), False)
```

to

```
band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("ORDERID"), False)
band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("ORDERDATE"), True)
```

It could be that the schema of the layout (`UltraWebGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0)`) is different to what is expected? I can't see why it should make a difference, but it's worth ruling it out.

Comment: its the same m8. I managed to fix it by taking the index of the column instead of just column(""). Thank you for your reply

Comment: Ah no worries. Do you mind posting how you fixed your problem as an answer, so that other people can learn from this and I can delete my answer, since it's of no value.